# Is there a way to change <h> tags generated by a plugin via jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up a page for ticket sales with the plugins Tickera and Woocommerce, currently I'm strugling to modify some texts that are generated from the plugins. Page I want to change https://shop.passarel-la.com/33-aniversari/ in the div with class tc-form-ticket-fields-wrap the h2 and h5 tags , been looking on the documentation of both plugins and couldn't find anything refering to those fields. Tried to add some jquery but seems to not work, is there a way to modify those tags?

Current script:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $span = jQuery('h2').find('tc-form-ticket-fields-wrap')
    jQuery('h2').text("Informacion Asistentes");
    jQuery('h2').append($span);
});
jQuery(function () {
    $span = jQuery('h2').find('tc-form-ticket-fields-wrap')
    jQuery('h5').text("Asistente ");
    jQuery('h5').append($span);
});
```

Comment: You have to add `.` or `#` to `.find('tc-form-ticket-fields-wrap')`.

Comment: personally I'd look for the source code where that html is generated by the plugin and edit it

Comment: What is the expected output? You want to turn H2 and H5 into spans?

Comment: @GrafiCode to change the text from h2 and h5 to something else, since that part is not supported by wpml so i could translate it.

Comment: `jQuery('div.tc-form-ticket-fields-wrap > h2').text('Informacion Asistentes');` and `jQuery('div.tc-form-ticket-fields-wrap > h5').text('Asistente');`

Comment: I swapped the script with your code and still doesn't work. However on jsfiddle both works.

Comment: I tried that code on your webpage, inputting it in the browser's console. That's why i wrote `jQuery` instead of `$`. If you try the same, pasting in the browser console, you'll see it works

Comment: The code is already with jQuery instead of $, maybe is beacause I load the script on the header.php on the theme folder?

Comment: Could be... Anyway, here is a screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/qBhH4Nc/sshot.png

Comment: be sure that code is executed on document ready, wrapping it inside `jQuery(document).ready( function() {  /* CODE HERE */  });`

Comment: i just added the document ready still doesn't load it. Here's how i load it maybe i made it wrong    <!-- WP_Head -->
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<!-- End WP_Head -->

<script type="text/javascript"
   src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/scriptmihai.js"></script>